# proof of functional completeness of logical operators

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, functional-completeness

If I know that the set of operators {∨, & , ¬} is functionally complete, how do I go about proving/disproving the functional completeness of the following set of operators?

a) $\{\vee,\neg\}$

b) $\{\to,\neg\}$

c) $\{\to\}$

I have looked at the answer here for (b) : 
[Prove that the set {→, ¬} is functionally complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481317/prove-that-the-set-%E2%86%92-%C2%AC-is-functionally-complete)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### a)

$\{\vee, \neg\}$ is functionally complete. You only have to show that $\wedge$ (alias $\&$) is definable from $\{\vee, \neg\}$, because then you can express all the connectives of the complete set $\{\vee, \wedge, \neg\}$ (and the functions they induce). Like so:
$$
p \wedge q \colon = \neg (\neg p \vee \neg q)
$$

#### b)

$\{\to, \neg\}$ is functionally complete. By a), it suffices to show that $\vee$ is definable from $\{\to, \neg\}$. Thus:
$$
p \vee q \colon = (\neg p \to q)
$$

#### c)

$\{\to \}$ is not functionally complete. The proof is by induction on the complexity of propositional formulas in two variables. Let $2 = \{0,1\}$ be the set of truth values. We show that the always-false function $$F_{false} \colon (u,v) \mapsto 0 \colon 2 \times 2 \to 2$$ is not definable.
Let
$$
\begin{align}
F_{\to} &\colon (u, v) \mapsto (\text{$1$ if $u\le v$ else $0$}) \colon 2 \times 2 \to 2 \\
\end{align}
$$
$F_{\to}$ is just the truth table for implication "$\to$".

For any propositional formula $A = A(p,q)$ in variables $p, q$, we define the function $f_A \colon 2 \times 2 \to 2$ corresponding to A, inductively:

$$
\begin{align}
f_p(u, v) &= u \tag{$pr_1$} \\
f_q(u, v) &= v \tag{$pr_1$} \\
f_{B\to C}(u,v) &= F_{\to}(f_B(u,v), f_C(u,v)) \tag{$Rule_{\to}$}
\end{align}
$$

***Induction on formulas***

Atomic formulas are $p$ and $q$. Clearly, neither $f_p$ nor $f_q$ is always false ($0$).

Now suppose $A$ is $B \to C$ with $B, C$ of lesser complexity (height, length). By induction hypothesis, neither $f_B$ nor $f_C$ is always false. Suppose $f_{B \to C}$ is always false:
$$f_{B \to C}(u,v) = 0 \;\;\text{for all $u, v$.}$$
By ($Rule_{\to}$), this means:
$$F_{\to}(f_B(u,v), f_C(u,v)) = 0 \;\;\text{for all $u, v$.}$$
By the definition of $F_{\to}$, this can only be so when 
$$
\begin{align}
f_B(u,v) &= 1 \;\;\text{for all $u, v$, and} \tag{i} \\
f_C(u,v) &= 0 \;\;\text{for all $u, v$.} \tag{ii} \\
\end{align}
$$
But by induction hypothesis, (ii) cannot be.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove the falsity of (iii) that does not involve induction?

Comment: Hmm good question. I couldn't think of one, anyway, or I would have used it assuming it was simpler. And if there really is *no other way* to prove it, that's harder still to prove (lol). Whatever the approach, you have to show that *some* function can't be expressed by any formula built up from 2 variables and implication. Perhaps there's some other theorem we could appeal to that would get rid of the induction -- maybe something involving "parity" of the truth function; but I'd bet that the proof of that theorem would be a much heavier induction. Basically, when you want to prove something..

Comment: (cont) about all formulas built up in a standard way, the standard approach is by induction on the construction of the formulas. I'll search a bit, though, see what I can see.

Comment: There is a theorem characterizing the functionally complete sets of connectives, but I doubted you could just cite it in your answer -- it's more high-powered. Here's what Emil Post proved, in the 1940s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness. This section (&probably the whole article) is also worth checking out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function#Functional_completeness

Comment: I have come across this statement:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional
If you look at the sentence just above the contents panel, you can see that they have expressed $p \to q$ in terms of &, OR and NOT. Doesn't that make it functionally complete?

Comment: expressing $\to$ in terms of $\vee$:
$\neg A \vee B$

expressing $\to$ in terms of $\wedge$:
$\neg(A \wedge \neg B)$

Would this be correct?

Comment: No: that's the "other direction". That just shows that you can express it using those other sets of connectives, which are known to be functionally complete :) Since e.g. "or" and "not" form a functionally complete sets, for example, of course you can express implication with them, because you can express every truth function with them.

Comment: "But by induction hypothesis, (ii) cannot be."
What are you referring to by (ii)?

Comment: I numbered the two last lines (look in right margin). (ii) is the statement "$f_C(u,v) = 0$, all u,v". The induction hypothesis is that for any formula D that's smaller than $B\to C$, $f_D$ is not the always-false function. In particular, $C$ is a smaller formula than $B\to C$, but (ii) says that it IS always false -- or anyway, it would have to be if $f_{A\to B}$ were always false. Last sentence means: the induction hyp. rules out (ii), therefore $f_{A\to B}$ is not always false. // So, there's no way to represent the always-false function. You *can* represent always-true: $f_{p\to p}$

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand the meaning of: Let $2={0,1}$ be the set of truth values. 

Is there a particular reason why you used "2"?

Comment: It's a convenient notation for a 2-element set, especially because in set theory it actually IS = {0,1} (the usual construction of the integers is: 0 = $\emptyset$, $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$). If you prefer {F,T} or explicit {0,1}, go ahead and use it. 2 just looks neater. If you use {F,T} you'll have to rephrase the definition of $F_{\to}$ but no big deal (F < T).

Comment: Would you show that $\{ \lnot, \leftrightarrow \}$ are not complete the same way? how would you do it?

Comment: @boozi Well, not really "the same" except in the broadest sense: that proof is also by structural induction on formulas, but the statement you prove inductively is quite different. There are several write-ups, search a little. (1) The question has been asked & answered here on SO: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556662/show-that-lnot-leftrightarrow-is-not-functional-complete. The answer by Bram28 (who answered this question too) is the best, but see my comment there on needed fixups. You may also find http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-hierarchy-of-logical-expressivity enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that $\{ \rightarrow \}$ is not complete:

We'll show by structural induction that for any expression $\phi(p,q)$ that is composed of any number of instances of variables $p$ and $q$, and any number of $\rightarrow$ connectives: $\phi(T,T)=T$.

Base: $\phi(p,q) = p$ and $\phi(p,q) = q$. In both cases we have $\phi(T,T)=T$

Step: Suppose $\phi(p,q) = \phi_1(p,q) \rightarrow \phi_2(p,q)$ and that (inductive hypothesis)  $\phi_1(T,T)=T$ and $\phi_2(T,T)=T$. Then $\phi(T,T) = \phi_1(T,T) \rightarrow \phi_2(T,T) = T \rightarrow T = T$

We have proven that for no such expression $\phi(T,T)=F$, and hence $\{ \rightarrow \}$ is not complete.