# functional completeness of $\{\to\}$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Given that the set {∨, $\wedge$ , ¬} is functionally complete, how would I prove whether the set $\{\to\}$ is functionally complete?

expressing $→$ in terms of $∨$: $¬A∨B$

expressing $→$ in terms of $∧$: $¬(A∧¬B)$

I understand the above two expressions, but cannot seem to prove that it is/is not functionally complete.

Comment: Your examples go the wrong way: they express $\implies$ in terms of other operations. To show $\{\implies\}$ is functionally complete, you would need to express the other operations in terms of $\implies$.

Comment: You say "expressing $\rightarrow$ in terms of $\vee$" (which can't be done) but then you express $\rightarrow$ in terms of  $\vee$ **and** $\neg$. So, when you say "is $\{\rightarrow\}$ functionally complete", do you mean "is $\{\rightarrow\}$ funcitonally complete", or do you mean "is $\{\rightarrow,\neg\}$ functionally comnplete"?

Comment: I meant is {→} functionally complete. I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have an expression $\pi$ involving propositional variables $A_1, . . . , A_n$, but only the connective "$\implies$" (OK, fine, and parentheses).

- What can I say about the truth value of $\pi$ if I assign "True" to each of the $A_1, . . . , A_n$?
- What does that tell you about whether $\{\implies\}$ is functionally complete?

Comment: The answer to your first bullet point: Would the truth value of $\pi$ be true?

Comment: Seems plausible - can you prove it? (The answer is yes, you're right - but this technically requires a proof.)

Comment: I have no idea of where to even start with the proof for that...the way in which I answered your question was just based off the definition of the operator itself

Comment: @user141834 also in the same boat, looking at a similar question. Not sure how to proceed

Comment: Well, let's start at the big picture: based on your guess - which is correct, but not yet proved - do you think $\{\implies\}$ is functionally complete? If so: why? If not: is there some expression you *don't* think you can use $\implies$ alone to define?

Comment: I don't think $\to$ is functionally complete, however that is a complete guess. With that being said, I don't think $\to$ can be used to define the $\wedge$ operator, simply because both have different truth tables..

Comment: @user141834 While it's correct that $\implies$ can't be used to define $\wedge$, that uses a different argument than the one which my hint above started. What's an expression that *isn't* made true if each of its components is true?

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to show that $\implies$ can't be used to define $\wedge$: try the same exercise as in my answer, but this time making each $A_i$ **false**. What happens now?

Comment: In line with the argument that you have used, an expression that isn't made true if each of its components are true is one which uses the $\neg$ operator. Is this correct?

Comment: @user141834 Sure - for instance, the expression "$\neg A_1$." If you believe that any expression involving only "$\implies$" (and parentheses) is made true when each of the propositional variables in it is made true, does this convince you that you can't express $\neg$ in terms of $\implies$ alone? If not: why not? If so: then you're halfway there - you just need to show that your answer to my exercise was, in fact, correct. (For that, here's a hint: **induction** . . .)

Comment: Ah I see. I had a feeling induction was coming, but induction on what property?

Comment: @user141834 Basically, you always want to induct on the *complexity* of the thing you're looking at, informally. So: what's a good way to measure the complexity of a formula? For instance, surely we agree that "$((B\implies C)\implies(A\implies C))\implies((A\implies B)\implies C)$" is more complicated than "$A\implies B$"; why?

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of complexity of the formula, could you explain further?

Comment: @Noah Schweber I've been through this with userNNN already, by the way.

Comment: I see, thanks. @user141834 the argument is exactly what BrianO did in the other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481376/proof-of-functional-completeness-of-logical-operators.